# Measuring current with multimeter (broken?)

Tags: multimeter

I just got my first multimeter from Home Depot and it was $60. It's the [Extech EX330](http://www.extech.com/instruments/product.asp?prodid=277) and it works fine except for when I measure current. I am doing it correctly and the fuse has not been blown. When I put it on the amp setting it reads .06 A when I put it on milli amp setting it reads .06 mA and when I put it on the micro Amp setting it reads .6 uA.  I have no idea if I should take it back or if I am just reading it wrong. Please help.

Comment: "Hi I just got my first multimeter from home depot and it was $60."  That could be your problem right there.

Comment: How would that be a problem

Comment: Sorry, I was being a bit cynical, but Home Depot isn't known for quality test equipment, and $60 isn't really what you would expect to pay for a good multimeter.  Obviously if it's reading wildly different currents on the different scales something is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have looked up this meter and have heard it is good for its price. And at school we have $20 meters that measure just fine so I'm pretty sure it's not the price.

Comment: @Trevor - 60$ is good enough, don't bother with buying more expensive models yet. Did you use "10A" socket when you measured current?

Comment: Um my circuit consisted of just 2 aa batteries a switch and a green led.

Comment: Also you might want to call your bank and cancel your credit card ;)  That does look a rather primitive meter.

Comment: @Trevor - I was asking about the socket on your meter. What label is printed on the socket where you inserted the probe?

Comment: Oh wow I feel stupid lol. 10A.

Comment: Yeap, that's the problem :) Feel free to answer the question yourself

Comment: Oh crap so the ma and ua are in the voltage side. Wow bad purchase?

Comment: I watched the video on the YouTube channel EEVlog and he said it was good.

Comment: No, it is normal for these meters

Comment: Ok so is it good enough for my level? (Beginner)

Comment: Yes, it's good enough. Just make sure you learn how to connect probes properly when you measure current or voltage.

Comment: Yeah I know I'm taking a class right now in school. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @Majenko The Extech EX330 is great for beginners. It was given decent [praises by EEVBlog](http://www.extech.com/instruments/press.asp?pressid=06072010) in a comparison of similar-priced entry-level meters.

Answer (score 4):

Not to point out the obvious, but reading [the manual](http://www.extech.com/instruments/resources/manuals/EX330_UM.pdf) seems like a good idea:

[image: Extech EX330 Current Measurement Manual Page]

I know you said you were measuring current correctly, measuring voltage versus current on most multimeters involves moving one of the test leads to a different jack on the meter. Usually current measurements are all done from a jack dedicated to current measurement. ***However steps 2 through 4 point out that measuring current at different ranges makes use of different ports.*** In this case, measurements from 0 to 400mA both use the same jack as for voltage measurements (V/mA/μA/CAP/Ω/Hz/Temp). I find this a bit unusual, but it could be somewhat convenient for low-current measurements.

As to why the meter shows the same digit (6) at different ranges, most likely because the meter was trying to read current from the jack which wasn't connected to anything during measurements.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you have to move the test prod to different sockets for current. If it's [this] (http://m.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Digital-Multimeter-MM1000/202521270) one then there are two positions for current. It's very important that they be returned to the voltage input before you attempt to measure volts.

Comment: Based on the model number and comments, I believe it is the [Extech EX330](http://www.extech.com/instruments/product.asp?prodid=277). Current measurement operation is much the same.